# Is there a specific Asus RT-N56U External HDD Format?

Tags: router, external-hard-drive, wireless-router

Tonight I setup my new Asus RT-n56u dual-band router. I love the thing. I can successfuly connect my two external HDD enclosure (containing 2x1TB drives) to the router. Unfortunately the router only sees 1TB and thinks it's entirely full. When I access the drive via Finder in OSX the drive appears empty and I can't see my partitions.

My assumption is that the Asus Firmware can only read a particular Filesystem type for the external disks which happens to not be the one I've used when reformatting my drives previously. Does anyone know if this is true, and if so which filesystem is needed?

For clarity, here's my setup:

- OSX Mountain Lion
- Brand new Asus RT-n56u
- [Custom Firmware 3.0.3.1-027](https://code.google.com/p/rt-n56u/)
- Rosewill dual hdd enclosure.
- 2x1TB hard drives in the enclosure.

Some other notes:

- Previous router was an Apple Time Capsule (slow)
- HDD Network Access via Finder with Time Capsule has worked to my expectation (I can see/read/write to each partition).
- I get the same behavior (drives 100% full, no files or partitions found) when using the firmware that came on the router pre-installed, as well as the most up-to-date version from ASUS' site (3.0.something).
- Data on the partitions mainly backups and media (music/photos/videos, etc.)

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: What format is the partition in? and is it an MBR partition table and not GPT? There is a good chance that it will not support GPT partitions, and you will also almost certainly need to format the drive in FAT32.

Comment: The drives are both Mac OS Journaled.

Comment: That's probably it. try changing to fat32

Answer (score 5):

I have this one. While it will read NTFS and FAT32 formats, it is quite slow at doing so. NTFS especially. The other limitation is file size and max hard drive size. I would recommend formatting the drive in EXT3. I find file transfer rates are much faster than with NTFS and I am using it with a 1TB drive.

You can see a comparison of file systems and their capabilities on the ASUS devices here
http://event.asus.com/2009/networks/disksupport/

> The drives are both Mac OS Journaled. – localshred Nov 29 at 15:50

ASUS only states that it can read FAT 16/32, EXT2/3, and NTFS file systems so you have to choose one of them.

One question, is your enclosure a RAID1 enclosure? that would explain the 2-1TB showing up as 1-1TB

Comment: Same experiences with tomato + ext3.